# Promise.all() is not resolving promises in the expected order

Tags: javascript, promise

If I understand Promise.all() correctly, I would expect this code to take 5 seconds before outputting **only** the reason for the rejected promise to the console.

```
function firstAsyncFunction() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    setTimeout(function(){
      resolve(console.log('First async function has been resolved!'));
    }, 500);
  });    
}

function secondAsyncFunction() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(function(){
      resolve(console.log('Second async function has been resolved!'));
    }, 2000);
  });
}

function thirdAsyncFunction() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {      
    setTimeout(function() {              
      reject('Internal server error'); // rejected for some reason
    }, 5000);    
  });
};

Promise.all([secondAsyncFunction(), firstAsyncFunction(), thirdAsyncFunction()])
    .then(function(values){        
      values.forEach(function(value){
        console.log(value);
      });

    }).catch(function(err){
      console.log(err);
    });
```

Instead, the first two promises resolve, **then** the final promise rejects. Additionally, the first two promises aren't even resolving in the order in which they are passed in to Promise.all(). Do I need to compose my promises differently to see the behavior I'm expecting?

***Edited***

Promise.all() does indeed wait until all the promises in the iterable passed into it resolve. My first clue was the fact that the console was outputting undefined (thanks Jaromanda X). If I remove the calls to console.log() in the resolve to firstAsyncFunction() and secondAsyncFunction() the following piece of code works exactly as I would expect:

```
function firstAsyncFunction() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    setTimeout(function(){
      resolve('First async function has been resolved!');
    }, 1000);
  });    
}

function secondAsyncFunction() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    resolve('Second async function has been resolved!');      
  });
}

function thirdAsyncFunction() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {      
    setTimeout(function() {      
      reject('Internal server error');
    }, 5000);
  });
};

Promise.all([
  thirdAsyncFunction(), 
  firstAsyncFunction(), 
  secondAsyncFunction()
])
 .then(function(values){        
   values.forEach(function(value){
     console.log(value);
   });
 })
 .catch(function(err){
   console.log(err);
 });
```

After five seconds I see "Internal server error" only. Promise.all() rejects the other promises even though they resolve sooner than the promise that was rejected. And yes, the values resolved by Promise.all() will be in the same order as the promises in the iterable passed in as a parameter. Thanks for all your help!

One more example:

```
function firstAsyncFunction() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    setTimeout(function(){
      resolve('First async function has been resolved!');
    }, 1000);
  });    
}

function secondAsyncFunction() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    resolve('Second async function has been resolved!');      
  });
}

function thirdAsyncFunction() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {      
    setTimeout(function() {
      resolve({
        users: [
          { name: 'Ronnie', age: 22 },
          { name: 'Bobby', age: 21 },
          { name: 'Ricky', age: 21 },
          { name: 'Mike', age: 20 }
        ]
      });
    }, 5000);
  });
};

Promise.all([thirdAsyncFunction(), firstAsyncFunction(), secondAsyncFunction()])
  .then(function(values){        
    values.forEach(function(value){
      console.log(value);
    });
  })
  .catch(function(err){
    console.log(err);
  });
```

After five seconds, this code will output:

```
{ users: 
   [ { name: 'Ronnie', age: 22 },
     { name: 'Bobby', age: 21 },
     { name: 'Ricky', age: 21 },
     { name: 'Mike', age: 20 } ] }
First async function has been resolved!
Second async function has been resolved!
```

Exactly what we want.

Comment: The order of the promises you feed to `Promise.all` is irrelevant.

Comment: torazaburo, that's not quite right. The values resolved by Promise.all() will be in the same order as the iterable you pass in as a parameter.

Comment: The important thing to realize here is that promises represent _the results of already started operations_. Thus any operator that takes promises and not functions for promises can't impose anything really.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Promise.all does not impose any order on the promises, they fulfill when they fulfill

the third promise "rejects" well after the other two "resolve", so the fact that the first two are resolved before the last is rejected is to be expected

by the way, your first two promises are resolving the value `undefined` and outputting to the console - which is why you may think that Promise.all is doing something it ought not be doing

> Do I need to compose my promises differently to see the behavior I'm expecting?

You wont get exactly the behaviour you are expecting, because you expect the promises to resolve in a particular order, the only way that can happen is for the promise to wait for the previous one to be fulfilled before it can fulfill, so the time would be cumulative, not in parallel, so in that case you wont get the rejection for 7.5 seconds rather than the 5 seconds you "expect"

Answer (score 1):

The `then` or the `catch` function of Promise.all is called only once all of the promises have resolved or one of the promises has been rejected. The individual promises can resolve in any order (that's the entire point of promises - they are asynchronous and can complete what they are supposed to whenever they like)

That said, it would be clearer if you tagged your Promise.all console.log differently, like so

```
Promise.all([secondAsyncFunction(), firstAsyncFunction(), thirdAsyncFunction()])
    .then(function (values) {
        values.forEach(function (value) {
            console.log('then:' + value);
        });

    }).catch(function (err) {
        console.log(err);
    });
```

You could be mixing up the console.logs in the promise and the one in the `then` callback.

Comment: Doh, I feel dumb. Your example reminded me that I needed to execute the functions in the array. This will probably trip up a lot of people coming from async.parallel because you just store the function and it executes for you.

Answer (score 1):

`Promise.all` runs all Promises that you pass it in parallel. This is useful when the Promises don't depend on each other and you need to perform both. For instance, in an integration test where you need to register two clients with a server. You need to wait for both to finish, but launching both at the same time will cut your wait roughly in half.

If you want to run them sequentially, you could chain your Promises, returning the result from one to the next:

```
firstAsyncFunction
  .then(secondAsyncFunction)
  .then(thirdAsyncFunction)
  .then(function(values) {
    console.log(values)
  }, function(err) {
    console.log(err);
  });
```

If you're looking to return aggregated data from all three calls, you'd also want to modify your promises to return their value in an array (or object). For example:

- firstAsyncFunction takes `userId` and returns `{ name: 'Bob' }`
- secondAsyncFunction takes `userObject` and returns `{ name: 'Bob', car: 'Porsche' }`
- thirdAsyncFunction takes `userObject` and returns `{ name: 'Bob', car: 'Porsche', kids: 5 }`

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to what others have said.

**Promise.all** does not run sequentially.

Here is an example of running async functions sequentially in ES6

```
/**
 * Runs async functions sequentially
 * @param Function[]
 * @return Promise<any>
 */
function runSequentially(functions) {
    return functions.reduce((promise, next) => {
        return promise.then(next);
    }, Promise.resolve());
}


/**
 * Full Example
 */

function foo()
{
    return new Promise(( resolve, reject )=>{
        resolve();
    })
}

function boo() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        resolve();
    })
}

function baz() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        resolve();
    })
}

const functions = [foo, boo, baz];

runSequentially(functions).then((result) => {

}).catch((error) => {

});
```

Comment: @Bergi , Works on my end. Iv updated the example to show the full example. 

https://jsfiddle.net/Bodman/8hp1p8cm/

Comment: `[foo, boo, baz]` are no promises. They are functions that return promises. Your code that explicitly annotates `promises` is an array of promises would not typecheck.

Comment: Yeah, good catch. Looks like it breaks on rejection. I'll fix it.

Comment: @Bergi should be fixed now. Thanks for the input !

Comment: No. Now it's not sequential any more - you really need to use `Promise.all` if you have an array of promises. The array of functions was fine - it's necessary for doing things sequentially - you just would need to have called it that