# Promises not resolving in the way I would expect

Tags: javascript, promise

I have the following:

```
for (let job of jobs) {
  resets.push(
    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      let oldRef = job.ref
      this._sequenceService.attachRef(job).then(() => {
        this._dbService.saveDoc('job', job).then(jobRes => {
          console.log('[%s / %s]: %s', oldRef, jobRes['jobs'][0].ref, this._moment.unix(job.created).format('DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm'))
          resolve()
        }).catch(error => {
          reject(error)
        })
      }).catch(error => {
        reject(error)
      })
    })
  )
}

return Promise.all(resets).then(() => {
  console.log('Done')
})
```

`this._sequenceService.attachRef` has a `console.log()` call.

When this runs, I am seeing all the console logs from the `this._sequenceService.attachRef()` call and then I see all the logs in the `saveDoc.then()` call. I was expecting to see them alternate. I understand that according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31893915/promise-all-is-not-resolving-promises-in-the-expected-order) article, promises don't resolve in order but I wouldn't expect my promise to resolve until I call `resolve()` so would still expect alternating logs, even if not in order.

Why is this not the case?

Comment: you can directly return the then function to array right without wrapping it in the promise

Comment: I did that initially but changed it to this so I can debug why the console logs are not in the order I expect. I thought trying to `resolve()` manually might help.

Comment: now its resolving correctly?

Comment: The logs will not alternate.. `Promise.all` fires all promises in parallel and in each case, the first request `this._sequenceService.attachRef` gets executed for all promises. They probably all finish before any of the second requests (`this._dbService.saveDoc('job', job)`) are completed

Comment: @ChiragRavindra - I understand that but doesn't `Promise.all` treat my `new Promise((resolve, reject))` as the promise to resolve and wait until I've called `resolve()` in order to determine it's resolved?

Comment: @zabusa - No, hence why I moved to this coding style to debug. I had that originally.

Comment: Yes. That should be the behaviour. But the logging happens whenever the `.then()` handler fires for each inner promise. I would expect `console.log('Done')` to be printed after everything. (ie, all the promises passed to `Promise.all` have been resolved

Comment: @ChiragRavindra Yes, that's correct about the done log but I still don't understand why the nested promises don't log in order. Surely, it has to pass each `then` call in order to hit my `resolve()` and in doing so has called `console.log`. That to me should mean the logs should be in order because `Promise.all` will ignore the nested promise but wait for my wrapped `resolve()`

Comment: all your promise in parallel right.may be you are seeing the console of other resolved promises in the middle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code can be written a lot cleaner by avoiding the [promise anti-pattern](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Promise-anti-patterns) of wrapping a promise in a new manually created promise.  Instead, you just push the outer promise into your array and chain the inner promises to the outer one by returning them from inside the `.then()` handler.  It can all be done as simply as this:

```
for (let job of jobs) {
    let oldRef = job.ref;
    resets.push(this._sequenceService.attachRef(job).then(() => {
        // chain this promise to parent promise by returning it 
        // inside the .then() handler
        return this._dbService.saveDoc('job', job).then(jobRes => {
            console.log('[%s / %s]: %s', oldRef, jobRes['jobs'][0].ref, this._moment.unix(job.created).format('DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm'));
        });
    }));
}

return Promise.all(resets).then(() => {
    console.log('Done')
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

Rejections will automatically propagate upwards so you don't need any `.catch()` handlers inside the loop.

---

As for sequencing, here's what happens:

- The `for` loop is synchronous.  It just immediately runs to completion.
- All the calls to `.attachRef()` are asynchronous.  That means that calling them just initiates the operation and then they return and the rest of your code continues running.  This is also called non-blocking.
- All `.then()` handlers are asynchronous.  The earliest they can run is on the next tick.
- As such this explains why the first thing that happens is all calls to `.attachRef()` execute since that's what the loop does.  It immediately just calls all the `.attachRef()` methods.  Since they just start their operation and then immediately return, the `for` loop finishes it's work pretty quickly of launching all the `.attachRef()` operations.
- Then, as each `.attachRef()` finishes, it will trigger the corresponding `.saveDoc()` to be called.
- The relative timing between when `.saveDoc()` calls finish is just a race depending upon when they got started (how long their `.attachRef()` that came before them took) and how long their own `.saveDoc()` call took to execute.  This relative timing of all these is likely not entirely predictable, particularly if there's a multi-threaded database behind the scenes that can process multiple requests at the same time.

The fact that the relative timing is not predictable should not be a surprise.  You're running multiple two-stage async operations purposely in parallel which means you don't care what order they run or complete in.  They are all racing each other.  If they all took exactly the same time to execute with no variation, then they'd probably finish in the same order they were started, but any slight variation in execution time could certainly change the completion order.  If the underlying DB gets has lock contention between all the different requests in flight at the same time, that can drastically change the timing too.

So, this code is designed to do things in parallel and notify you when they are all done.  Somewhat by definition, that means that you aren't concerned about controlling the precise order things run or complete in, only when they are all done.

Comment: Brilliant explanation, many thanks. Just to note, I used the anti pattern only when debugging as I wanted to make sure it wasn't just the way I was doing it before (which is how you've described it should be done). I do actually want it working like it is (just let me know when all is done) but was curious as to why the ordering wasn't as I expected. I understand now.

Answer (score 2):

Clarifying my comments above:

In this case the promises are at four levels.

Level 0: Promise created with `Promise.all`

Level 1: Promise created with `new Promise` for each Job

Level 2: Promise as generated by `this._sequenceService.attachRef(job)`

Level 3: Promise as generated by `this._dbService.saveDoc('job', job)`

Let's say we have two jobs J1 and J2

One possible order of execution:

```
L0 invoked

J1-L1 invoked
J2-L1 invoked

J1-L2 invoked
J2-L2 invoked

J1-L2 resolves, log seen at L2 for J1
J1-L3 invoked

J2-L2 resolves, log seen at L2 for J2
J2-L3 invoked

J1-L3 resolves, log seen at L3 for J1
J1-L1 resolves

J2-L3 resolves, log seen at L3 for J2
J2-L1 resolves

L0 resolves, 'Done' is logged
```

Which is probably why you see all L2 logs, then all L3 logs and then finally the `Promise.all` log

Comment: Right, Ok, that's very clear now, thanks. I don't suppose you have way to make it work the way I'm expecting do you?

Comment: I sometimes use An array of Promise factories (functions which return promises) in conjunction with a reduce call on the array to build a sequential promise chain (instead of `Promise.all`) when the order is important.. Ex: `promisefactoryArray.reduce((chain,pf)=>(chain.then(()=>pf())), Promise.reolve())`However, detailing the solution here I feel is out of scope for the way this question is framed.. You could also look at async/wait library to force sequential execution.

Comment: That's fine, thanks. I agree it's out of scope. I'll probably just await it in this instance now I understand what's going on under the hood a little better.

Comment: Sorry but I've marked the other answer as correct for this one as it goes into more detail about what's happening and why. I do appreciate your time and effort helping me understand though.

Comment: No worries! Whatever answers the question best :)